# Getting access denied on Amazon S3 put object for encryption policy

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

I am trying to upload a file using Java to Amazon S3 bucket.

I have the below policy which should restrict the files that not encrypted.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "PutObjPolicy",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "DenyUnEncryptedObjectUploads",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:PutObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::file-upload-test/*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringNotEquals": {
                    "s3:x-amz-server-side-encryption": "AES256"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Now, when I try to use the below code, I get Access Denied exception.

```
com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Access Denied (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: AccessDenied; Request ID: F287836ABBF2B486)
```

The java code that I am using is:

```
    ObjectMetadata objectMetadata = new ObjectMetadata();
    objectMetadata.setContentLength(fileSize);   
        objectMetadata.setSSEAlgorithm(ObjectMetadata.AES_256_SERVER_SIDE_ENCRYPTION);
    objectMetadata.setContentType(contentType);
    putObjectRequest = new PutObjectRequest(bucketName, fileName, inputStream, objectMetadata);
    s3client.putObject(putObjectRequest);
```

Is this correct that I should use this Java code to achieve this?

If yes, then what modifications are required.
If no, then should I use encryption at client end?

Please suggest.

Comment: Do the credentials that your Java program is using actually have permission to write to that S3 bucket?

Comment: @jarmod Yes, If I don't write policy in AWS S3 console I am able to upload the file

Comment: Could you do a sanity check using the awscli (aws s3 cp cat.png s3://file-upload-test/ --sse AES256) using the same set of credentials?